# Odoo Email template render error

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I'm sending email from module @override create method here is my method

```
@api.model
def create(self, values):
    res = super(licenses, self).create(values)
    template = self.env.ref('licenses.license_create_email_template', False)
    # Send out the e-mail template to the user
    self.env['mail.template'].browse(template.id).send_mail(res, force_send=True)
    return res
```

here is my template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <record id="license_create_email_template" model="mail.template">
            <field name="name">License Create</field>
            <field name="email_from">${user.email|safe}</field>
            <field name="subject">License Create</field>
            <field name="email_to">${object.x_partner_id.email}</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="licenses.model_licenses_licenses"/>
            <field name="auto_delete" eval="True"/>
            <field name="lang">${object.x_partner_id.lang}</field>
            <field name="body_html"><![CDATA[
             The License of ${object.x_partner_id.name} has been created.
        ]]></field>
       </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

When i preview template from setting it rendering correctly but when i render email template from code it gives render error here is render error picture
[(Picture)Email template render problem error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WREsY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the parameters for `send_mail` method of `mail.template` model is `res_id` that is an integer, take a look its [definition](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/6f68beb0dcd82c8365d057133107c3be78eb4cc7/addons/mail/models/mail_template.py#L550). And if you are using .v10 new api, acording to the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.models.Model.create) `create` method returns a recordset not an integer, therefore you sould get the `id` from that record set in this way `res.id` and pass it as a parameter of `send_mail`.

I hope this answer can be helpful for you.